# I have two points p1:(x1,y1) and p2:(x2,y2) and a curve(sometimes an arc, no specific shape) is drawn from p1 to p2

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, geometry

I want to find the tangent angle at `p2`. I think `y2-y1 / x2-x1` will give the slope, if the points `p1` and `p2` are on a line. And does `tan ((y2-y2)/(x2-x1))` give the tangent angle ?? And also if `p1` and `p2` are on an arc how can I get the angle of the tangent of the arc at `p2` ?

Can anyone help me on this please ??

**Edit:**
To be more specific, I'm moving a boat through the path from p1 to p2. And I want to change the direction of the boat according to the tangent angle at p2, so that the boat's front will always point in the direction of the path. Consider the wiki image at http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Graph_of_sliding_derivative_line.gif

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious you need to be more specific about what you are trying to do. You write "if the points p1 and p2 are on a line" - given any two points you can draw a line between them, so they're always on some line... And you say the arc has "no specific shape" - there are an infinite number of arcs passing through p1 & p2 and each has its own tangent.

Comment: @CRD I mean a path which has no shape, it may be an arc or line, etc.

Comment: “A path which has no shape” - this makes no sense.  How is the path defined?  What data structure is it in?  What do the elements of that data structure represent?  Alteratively, what API do you use to access and manipulate the path?  Edit your question to include these details.

Comment: From the link you provided, it appears that you would want to change the heading of the boat all along the arc, not just at p2. Is that what you want?

Comment: @rdelmar yeah that is exactly the thing i want, p1 and p2 are arbitrary points on the route of the boat, the path from p1 to p2 represent a small portion in the long route of the boat. It changes from time to time. if i get it for p2 then i can use the logic wherever i need.

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions.  How you calculate the slope at `p2` (either exactly or by approximation) depends entirely on how the path is defined at point `p2`.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe you just want to use a `CAKeyframeAnimation` with `rotationMode` set to `kCAAnimationRotateAuto` and let the system take care of rotating your boat to match the tangent of the path.

Comment: @robmayoff I am now calculating the slope by taking very small distances of the route considering it as lines. Since I dont have any centre to consider the path as an arc or something.

Comment: @robmayoff I want to rotate the object programmatically and store the rotation value for the boat at each change in rotation. Thats why i need to find the tangent angle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by vector math. Here's a basic idea to get your boat point in the direction of travel on curve every time:

1. You'll have to get the equation of the curve on which the boat will move.
2. Suppose the boat is at point p1 on the curve.
3. Decide a distance d1 of about 0.5% of the total length of curve.
4. Get a point pBack at distance d1 backwards to p1 on curve.
5. Get a point pFront at distance d1 forward to p1 on curve.
6. Now we have a vector v1 = ( pFront.x - pBack.x , pFront.y - pBack.y )
7. Find the angle between v1 and v2 = (1,0) by doing dot-product between them.
8. Once you have the angle simply perform a rotation-translation on your boat object.

Reference for Vector Algebra : http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html